# Does Apache Beam's RedisIO batch write requests to the server?

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

There isn't alot of literature on the RedisIO package in the Apache Beams java sdk. Out of curiousity is there a mechanism to modify how the SDK batches requests to the redis server when making WRITE requests?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it adds the records into a local batch and flushes the whole batch once it exceeds the default number of records (1000). I don't think that this number can be changed (see details [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/3a5b52cd112ab7aad894808cf08775fe93adf7f4/sdks/java/io/redis/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/redis/RedisIO.java#L599)).